# Having trouble lining a larger div box over a smaller one

Tags: html, css

i have this div that i'm trying to use as a title and i'm trying to overlay that  on top of another div called wrapper. Something is causing it to not line up correctly in any of my browsers. I've tried using relative postion. And messing with the width and left/right positioning properties. But when I try they don't lie up correctly. They just push from one corner to another like if the content control width size is not big enough.  I know the code is a bit confusing here so here is the jsfiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/fn5c9w3j/

```
.textwrapper{
background-color: #66CCFF;
height: 70px;
width: 1250px;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
left: 300px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: How do you want them to line up? For reference, [this is what the code you posted looks like right now.](https://jsfiddle.net/f80wo11w/1/)

Comment: I'm sorry without the theme loaded it looks like that. I want the Video Section div box to overlay on top of another div box that has all my videos in it. Which is div with class wrapper.

Comment: Do you have a web page or site where we can see exactly what you're talking about? ex. JSFiddle or your own site.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle of of project https://jsfiddle.net/fn5c9w3j/

Comment: Im just trying to line the video section div box over the video div boxes i have under it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem, put text wrapper inside wrapper:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="textwrapper" >VIDEO SECTION</div>
  <div id="section" align="center">  
    <br>
```

Then style it:

```
.textwrapper
{
 background-color:#66ccff;
 height:70px;
 width:1200px;
 position:absolute;
 vertical-align:middle;
 left:2px;
 z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: The stupid jsfiddle link has to have 4 lines of code accompany with it.

Comment: No worries, happy to help.